# How to handle session and cookies between HTML5 and Native in Hybrid environment (same domain, multiple domains)

Tags: session, hybrid

We are developing both native (iOS, Android) and internet application (HTML5 web content).
In Native application we have requirement to call "HTML5 web content" using URL of of web content, which is hosted on a Server.

Question #1- In this HYBRID approach, in case of single and multiple domains, how the session is managed between Native. Here single domain means, both Web and Native are using same server, where as multiple domains means, the Native and Web are using different servers.

Question#2- How Native knows about session timeout happens in Web?